# how can I remove maven check-style violation?

Tags: maven-checkstyle-plugin

.java:[34] (whitespace) EmptyLineSeparator: 'CLASS_DEF' should be separated from previous statement.

I tried giving the line before the code but after that when I hit mvn eclipse:eclipse it shows to non-complying  file and suggest to run mvn com.coveo:fmt-maven-plugin:format and the given extra line revert back to the previous code. I am stuck in this loop.

Comment: It is hard to say without any code-examples. Are you using maven, can you reproduce your problem using a minimal reproducible example? => https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example